# Why does calling Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")[109] cause my program to crash?

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofrangeexception

When I call

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")[109].GetAttribute("src")
```

The program crashes with an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.  However, when I call

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")[99].GetAttribute("src")
```

the program successfully runs without an exception being thrown.  The only difference is the 99 vs. 109, why does this cause a crash?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error you get?  Perhaps `IndexOutOfRangeException` or `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 3):

The [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is thrown when the caller attempts to get an element that is out of the bounds of the collection.  If the collection has 10 items, and you try to access the 10th, 11th, or 100th index, this exception will be thrown.

When an exception is thrown and unhandled, the runtime will terminate your program (i.e. your program will "crash"). You can find more information about C# exceptions and exception handling [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx).

This is what is happening to you; perhaps there are only 100 items, and the 99th index is the last item in the collection.  In any event, there is not an item at the index 109, so this exception is thrown.  When the exception goes unhandled, the CLR will terminate your program.

In order to prevent this exception from being thrown, be sure to check the size of the array and request items inside those bounds.

For example:

```
int numberOfImages = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img").Count;
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++)
{ 
    var src = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")[i].GetAttribute("src");
    //use src here
}
```

You can also avoid the pesky `int` indexer altogether by using `foreach`:

```
foreach(var image in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img"))
{
    var src = image.GetAttribute("src");
    //use src here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i did this. basically I take the first yahoo image. it works, thanks for your help

```
 private  void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://it.images.search.yahoo.com/images");
    }
    int a = 1;
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (a == 1)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("yschsp").InnerText = textBox1.Text;
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")[1].InvokeMember("click");
            do
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            } while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete);
            await PutTaskDelay();
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")[0].GetAttribute("src");
            a = a + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("yschsp").InnerText = textBox1.Text;

            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sbx_x").InvokeMember("click");
            do
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            } while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete);
            await PutTaskDelay();
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")[0].GetAttribute("src");
        }
    }
    async Task PutTaskDelay()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
```